# How do I get the output of a command inside a taskfile variable?

Tags: taskfile

How do I get the output of a command inside a [taskfile](https://taskfile.dev/) variable?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning a string to a variable, use a map and `sh` key to mention the command to be executed.

```
vars:
  FOO: bar
  CURRENT_DATE:
    sh: date
```